Testing @Scheduled annotation starts more than one thread
I have a Spring Boot application and I created a method with the @Scheduled annotation that takes a cron expression as parameter (let's say it needs to run every 5 seconds). The scheduled method is as follows (by way of example I only put a printout on the screen)
@Component
public class ElaborazioneEventi {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElaborazioneEventi.class);
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")
    public void elaborazioneEventi() throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + new Date());
        
    }

The configuration for scheduling is the single @EnableScheduling annotation on the main application class.
For my application, there are several JUnit test classes (that do not test scheduled methods) and two classes that test two methods annotated with @Scheduled.
The test class of interest for this discussion is the following:
@SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(Application.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ElaborazioneEventiTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private A4gtNprElaborazioneEventoRepository a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoRepository;
    
    @Test
    @Sql(scripts = {"/sql/eventi/delete_elaborazione_eventi.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
    @Sql(scripts = {"/sql/eventi/insert_elaborazione_eventi.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
    @Sql(scripts = {"/sql/eventi/delete_elaborazione_eventi.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
    
    public void batchGiaInEsecuzioneTest() throws InterruptedException {
        List<A4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel> eventi = a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("eventi presenti: " + eventi.size());
        
        A4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel = new A4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel();
        a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel.setDataInizioElaborazione(new Timestamp(Utils.convertStringToDate("24/12/2024 13:41:55", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS").getTime()));
        a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel.setFlagStopElaborazione(new BigDecimal(0));
        a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel.setStatoElaborazione(new BigDecimal(0));
        a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoRepository.save(a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoModel);
        
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        
        eventi = a4gtNprElaborazioneEventoRepository.findAll();
        
        System.out.println("eventi presenti dopo la insert: " + eventi.size());
                        
        assertTrue(eventi.size() == 2);
    }
}

What I noticed is that if I start the application normally, an execution starts every 5 seconds, while when the test classes are started (I test the test classes all together), it is as if the application starts and then the method starts scheduled when it has not yet managed to execute the test for that method. I also noticed that an execution does not start every 5 seconds, but several executions start at the same time every 5 seconds, as can be seen from the following log (I managed to extract only these log lines):
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:00 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool2 Sun Dec 29 09:41:00 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool2 Sun Dec 29 09:41:00 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:00 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:00 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool2 Sun Dec 29 09:41:05 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:05 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool2 Sun Dec 29 09:41:05 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:05 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:05 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:10 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:10 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:10 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:10 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool5 Sun Dec 29 09:41:10 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool5 Sun Dec 29 09:41:15 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool2 Sun Dec 29 09:41:15 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:15 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool3 Sun Dec 29 09:41:15 CET 2024
eventStoreSchedulerMultiEventPool1 Sun Dec 29 09:41:15 CET 2024

With each execution the number of threads increases. Initially, 2 start at the same time, then every 5 seconds others are added. What I want is that only one instance of the scheduled method starts during the execution of the JUnit tests, as rightly happens if I run the application. How should I configure JUnit to make this happen?

Your test is weird are you using JUnit4 or JUnit5? Each different configuration will lead to a new application being loaded and thus job being scheduled. So if you have multiple @SpringBootTest in your test package, with different @SQL, @Mock, properties or whatever it will start a new instance.

the Junit version is 5.8.2 but I don't think the reason is what you tell me because, if that were the case, I should have 13 threads in my test package that would start every 5 seconds, given that in the package I have 13 classes with the annotation @SpringBootTest, while when on eclipse I run > Junit on the ser/test/java package only one application is loaded and every 5 seconds, the number of threads increases until it reaches 5 or 7. What I want to understand is how can I ensure that only one thread is launched every 5 seconds?

That is not what I'm saying every permutation of different configurations will load a new application context. So if 13 classes but if only 5 have differnt configs/settings only those will start a new application. If you are using JUnit5 ditch the @RunWith and the SpringJUnitConfig. To prevent don't use different configs/settings so that you reuse 1 context.

I tried deleting the annotations and configuration classes, as you suggested, but it didn't solve the problem. I keep getting multiple instances every 5 seconds

I feel like I'm a record... For each permutation of configuration a new application will be started. Just removing the @RunWith and @SpringJunitConfig won't solve it . As stated each permutation of @Sql, @MockBean, @TestPropertySource, @Profile and many many more will lead to a new application being started.
